# Algorithm for blindly navigating a physical labyrinth

Tags: algorithms

I was recently in Maastricht and visited the caves and tunnels that lie under the city. (http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/fort-saint-pieter) While on a tour we were told that on numerous occaisions people have lost their light sources and have been unable to make their way out.

https://nltimes.nl/2015/08/05/21-hour-ordeal-lost-maastricht-students-rescued-cave

This made me wonder: is there an algorithm that you would be able to physically execute in real life, having found yourself in a similar situation.

Comment: Wikipedia describes several [maze solving algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm).

Comment: Probably not. Unless the walls are simply connected, the left-hand/right-hand/wall-following algorithm won't work; any other algorithm relies on being able to see at least your current location so you know what your local options are and, in some cases, so you can leave marks on the floor. (Repost to fix a significant typo I found much too late to edit.)